# `devtools::check()` deletes log files

Tags: r, logging, package, devtools

When I run `devtools::check()` I can see that errors and warnings and notes are appearing but `devtools::check()` stores these results in `/tmp` so they're deleted almost instantly. I want to be able to see the log files and know what happened.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that controls where these files are stored, so how can I save these logs in a more permanent location?